Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Data.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ...'
In my C# .Net Framework v4.8 project, I have installed few packages including Nunit console runner and Dapper. When i build i am not getting any error but in jenkins while intrumenting i am getting the below error. If i remove any one of this packages, then i am not getting this error. Please help me to resolve this.
ERROR *** Instrumentation phase failed
Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Data.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
